# Установка программы nemesis

Tags: linux, установка, kali-linux

я читаю книгу "Хакинг. Искусство эксплойта" и там идёт разбор программы nemesis. Я поискал в интернете и нашёл её на GitHub-е, но у меня не получилось установить её , хотя я полностью выполнял все инструкции. Поэтому я спрашиваю здесь: как установить nemesis? ОC-Kali Linux

Comment: Ну раз на гитхабе, то наверняка скомпилировать.

Comment: Можно более развёрнуто объяснить?

Comment: Есть здесь: https://losst.ru/kompilyatsiya-programm-linux

Comment: Спасибо. Изучил статью и смог все установить. Оказалось надо было использовать make install

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/130868/